# Typescript method as ng-repeat custom filter not behaving as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

```
module ngrFilter{
    'use strict';

    export class UsersCtrl {

        public userCollection: any[];
        public userFilter: string;

        constructor(){
            this.userCollection = [{id:1,name:'John',surname:'Klopper'},
                                   {id:2,name:'Mary',surname:'Schoeman'}];
        }

        public filterUser(user){
            //The this is undefined when using as a custom filter for ng-repeat
            console.log(this.userFilter)

            if(user.name == this.userFilter ||
               user.surname == this.userFilter){
              return true;
            }  
        }
    }

    angular
        .module('ngrFilter',[])
        .controller('UsersCtrl', UsersCtrl);
}
```

When using a custom filter for ng-repeat the `this` property is undefined in the filterUser method. Is there a way to get this filter to work or am I just doing something stupid.

I also tried adding a sample of the code here: http://fiddlesalad.com/typescript/custom-ngrepeat-filter/

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but this: `if(user.name == this.userFilter ||
               user.surname == this.userFilter){
              return true;
            }  `  could be simplified to `return (user.name == this.userFilter || user.surname == this.userFilter);` (assuming that you want to return false if the condition doesn't hold - in your code, it seems you forgot to handle that case).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of a method, use a public field as filter function, which can create a closure for this.

```
export class UsersCtrl {
    public userCollection: any[];
    public userFilter: string;
    public filterUser: (User) => boolean;

    constructor(){
        this.userCollection = [{id:1,name:'John',surname:'Klopper'},
                               {id:2,name:'Mary',surname:'Schoeman'}];
        var self = this;
        this.filterUser = function(user:User) {
            return self./*...*/;      
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do can be done via an [angular filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)

For what you're trying to do I would just handle an event and rebind the list upon changing of the filter

```
export class UsersCtrl {

    public userCollection: any[];
    public filteredUserCollection: any[];
    public userFilter: string;

    constructor(){
        this.userCollection = [{id:1,name:'John',surname:'Klopper'},
                               {id:2,name:'Mary',surname:'Schoeman'}];
        this.filteredUserCollection = this.userCollection;
    }

    public filterChanged(filter){
        this.filterUser(filter);
    }

    public filterUser(filter){
        var results = [];
        if(user.name == filter ||
           user.surname == filter){
          results.push(user);
        }
        this.filteredUserCollection = results;
    }
}
```

And then your markup would change to:

```
<input ng-model="users.userFilter" ng-change="users.filterChanged(users.userFilter)">
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="user in users.filteredUserCollection">
        {{user.name}} {{user.surname}}
    </li>
</ul>
```